# How to strech the background image of a div according to mobile view

Tags: css, responsive-design

So I am trying to create a responsive website but I am not able to fit the background image when reduced to mobile size.What I intend is that background image crops from both side equally to center the image.

Here's what I have tried:

```
.top {
    background-image: url("./images/desktop/image-header.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Desktop view :

[image]

After media query :

```
.top {
        background-image: url("./images/desktop/image-header.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100vw 100vh;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
```

Result achieved:

[image]

Intended result:

[image]

As we can see what I did was to compress the image from both sides,but from expected result I think we need to crop the images from both sides to fit in the orange in center.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you upload the img? Is it square? At what media max width or height do you want it to crop right to the edge of the orange, and do you want it cropped in some way proportionally above that to some maximum (ie the blue gets less the smaller the viewport?)

Answer (score 0):

Just crop the image on photoshop as you want on mobile screen then **@media screen** replace the background-image url with cropped one

Comment: Well I am doing this as a part of challenge and I have to make due with what I have been provided.